# Fill-reducing ordering for computing the matrix product $A^T A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have found many libraries for reducing filling when dong Cholesky factorisation on sparse matrices. However, I want to do fill-reduction for a different reason - given a $m\times n$ matrix $A,$ I want to find a permutation matrices $P,Q$ such that $B=PAQ$ satisfy the property that $B^\ast B$ is as sparse as possible. This is useful for, for instance, finding singular values, or solving optimisation problems.

Is there a fill-reduction library for the purpose I describe?

Comment: If $A$ is sparse could you not instead implement the matrix vector product with $A^TA$ through $y=Ax$ and $z=A^Ty$ and then $z=A^TAx$ as desired? As long as you're using iterative methods you can use this. Looking for a sparsity promoting fill-reducing ordering sounds like a much harder and computationally more expensive problem.

Comment: @lightxbulb Thank you for the suggestion. But I want to SOLVE linear system of the form $A^TAx = b.$ Does your method here work?

Comment: Insofar as you use an iterative solver that requires products with $A^TA$ it does work. Are you by chance solving the normal equations $A^TAx=A^Tc$? If yes then look up CGNR/CGLS/LSQR. If not then you can maybe still use those, you just need to modify the first step to not apply the $A^T$ to $b$. Or you can use just the conjugate gradient solver with the matrix-vector multiplication as described.

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible. If $P$ and $Q$ are permutation matrices, then their inverses, respectively, are $P^T$ and $Q^T$. Also note that, applying permutations to a matrix $A$ doesn't change its number of nonzeros (which is intuitively trivial, but has a slightly long proof which I am going to skip).

Now, let $B=PAQ$ and consider $$B^TB = Q^TA^TP^TPAQ = Q^TA^TAQ.$$
So $B^TB$ is $A^TA$ symmetrically permuted and we can conclude $B^TB$ has the same number of nonzeros as $A^TA$.

Comment: Wow, great answer. That's so obvious and yet not very intuitive at the first thought.